# Scrolling to a selected item in an observable collection in Xamarin c#

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to automatically scroll to the selected item in my collection view. Am using an ObservableCollection and am able to pre-select an item in my view. So I want it to appear on the screen to be seen incase the items are many.

So the view should automatically scroll to the selected item.

Code

```
public ObservableCollection WorkerFlockDetails { get; set; }

private WorkerFlock selectedFlock;
    public WorkerFlock SelectedFlock
    {
        get => selectedFlock;
         set
        {
            if (selectedFlock != value)
            {
                try
                {
                    //Feed = selectedFlock.Feed_intake.ToString() + " Kg";
                    selectedFlock = value;
                }
                catch
                {

                }
                finally
                {
                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedFlock)));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is where I initialize and pre-select

```
public HomeWorkerViewModel()
    {

        WorkerFlockDetails = new ObservableCollection<WorkerFlock>();

        //populate the collection
        Init();

        
        SelectedFlock = WorkerFlockDetails.Skip(3).FirstOrDefault();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the code below and set the ScrollTo method in OnAppearing prior to the page becoming visable.

Xaml:

```
  <CollectionView x:Name="collectionView"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding WorkerFlockDetails}" 
                    ItemsLayout="HorizontalList" 
                    SelectionMode="Single"  
                     VerticalOptions="Start"
                        Margin="0,22,0,0"
                        HeightRequest="32"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFlock, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}"  Margin="20,0,20,0"
                           TextColor="#707070"
                           FontSize="20"></Label>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

Code behind:

```
  public partial class Page19 : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<WorkerFlock> WorkerFlockDetails { get; set; }
    public WorkerFlock SelectedFlock { get; set; }
    public Page19()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        WorkerFlockDetails = new ObservableCollection<WorkerFlock>()
        {
            new WorkerFlock(){ Name="A"},
            new WorkerFlock(){ Name="B"},
            new WorkerFlock(){ Name="C"},
            new WorkerFlock(){ Name="D"},
            new WorkerFlock(){ Name="E"},
            new WorkerFlock(){ Name="F"},
            new WorkerFlock(){ Name="G"}
        };
        SelectedFlock = WorkerFlockDetails.Skip(3).FirstOrDefault();

        this.BindingContext = this; 
    }
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        collectionView.ScrollTo(collectionView.SelectedItem, null, ScrollToPosition.Center, false);
    }
}
public class WorkerFlock
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .ScrollTo(); method on the CollectionView for this.